# Rewrite module as vezes da erro 500

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Estou fazendo um projeto, e aprendi a pouco tempo sobre a reescrita de `URL's`, fiz conforme vi nos tutoriais porém as vezes quando tento acessar o endereço o navegador retorna `erro 500`, seria esse algum problema com meu `htaccess`? esse é o código que estou usando

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^navegar/?$ inicio.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Estou usando o mesmo padrão de reescrita para todas as páginas e o mesmo erro persiste com todas, o que há de errado?

Comment: Detalhes do erro devem estar no log de erros do Apache. Leia o log para mitigar o problema antes de aplicar qualquer solução a esmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu acho q vc esta esquecendo o rewrite base
tente assim

segue ex do meu que eu utilizo no meu serv.
Obs: o mod rewrite do apache tem que estar ativo se não vai dar erro 500 mesmo

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ inicio.php?cod=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: O erro permanece, aparece Erro 500, as vezes dou F5 e carrega e as vezes o erro aparece novamente, o module_rewrite está ativado no Apache

Comment: vc esta usando on ou offline?

Comment: pois se as vezes funciona e as vezes não sem vc mexer em nada o problema pode esta no seu apache.

Comment: Estou usando o On, minha preocupação é que seja com o apache do Wamp, por isso perguntei pois não quero esse tipo de erro quando o site estiver online

Comment: melhro coisa q vc faiz he instalar numa vmware ai um debian ou centos ou ubuntu com apache mysql e php e testar isso.
ou ter um serv online para vc fazer testes.

Comment: vou tentar fazer o teste aqui em um server online, vlw pela atenção

Comment: c nao de certo m avisa, c der vota plus ai ^^